# No response from [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]

Tags: macos, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to setup in-app purchases for my Mac app. Purchasing products works fine but I was not able to get [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] working.

A transaction observer is set (otherwise purchasing would not work) and use [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] to restore all previous purchases.

StoreKit should now use ***paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:*** to restore the transactions and ***paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:*** or ***paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:*** to report success or failure. But non of these methods are called. There is absolutely no response.

If I use [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] I get the following output:

> Ignoring restoreCompletedTransactions because already restoring transactions

There a lot of discussions where restoreCompletedTransactions returns an empty result. But in my case there is simply no result.

How can I find out what is going wrong?

Comment: it's been a long time but... did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK InApp Purchases cannot be tested in Simulator.

**You need a real device to test on**!